# Return the number of times that the string "hello" appears anywhere in the given string

Tags: java

```
public int count(String str){

    int count=0;
    int index=str.indexOf("Hello");
    System.out.println(index);
    while(index!=-1)
    {
        index=str.indexOf("Hello",index+1);

        count++;

    }
    return count;

}
```

Problem when I passes test cases.

```
Testcase    Pass/Fail   Parameters           Actual Output  Expected Output
#1             Pass     'Hello how are you'       1               1
#2             Fail     'HELLO how are you'       0               1
```

Comment: Try converting everything to lower case before entering your loop.

Comment: When you were asking this question and your two previous ones, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it.  There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scan past it to find the button) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
public int count(String str){

    int count=0;
    String str1="";
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        char ch=str.charAt(i);
        if(ch>=65 && ch <=90){
        ch=(char)(ch + 32);
       str1=str1 + ch;
        }
        else
        str1=str1+ch;
    }
   int index=str1.indexOf("hello");
   System.out.println(index);
   while(index!=-1)
   {
       index=str1.indexOf("hello",index+1);

       count++;

   }
   return count; 

}
```

Comment: Happy to help.. @nisha

Answer (score 4):

Java is (extremely) case sensitive. `Hello` is not the same as `HELLO`.

What you can do, is turn the original `String` into lowercase, and search for occurrences of `hello`.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the point about case sensitivity.

You can try as follows..

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(count("Hello how are you"));
}

public static int count(String str) {
   String[] arr=str.split(" ");
    int count=0;
   for(String i:arr){
       if(i.equalsIgnoreCase("hello")){
           count++;
       }
   }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the source code of [`indexOf()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.indexOf%28char%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cchar%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29) It compare string character by character by converting it to char array So `e` is not equal to `E` and it fails there.

Answer (score 0):

with the java8 stream API:

```
private static long count(String string) {
    return Arrays.asList(string.split(" ")).parallelStream().map(str -> str.toLowerCase())
            .filter(str -> "hello".equals(str)).count();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s1 = "Hello how are you";
    System.out.println(Long.toString(count(s1)));
    String s2 = "HELLO how are you";
    System.out.println(Long.toString(count(s2)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Return the number of times that the string "hello" appears anywhere in the given string.

public class CountHello {
    static String testcase1 = "Hello! hello! how are you";

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    CountHello testInstance= new CountHello();
    int result = testInstance.count(testcase1);
    System.out.println(result);
}

public int count(String str1){
    //write your code here
String str2="Hello";
int len1=str1.length();
int len2=str2.length();
int count=0;

for(int i=0;i<(len1-len2+1);i++)
{       String str="";
    for(int j=i;j<i+len2;j++)
    {
        str=str+str1.charAt(j);
        if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(str2)) count++;  
    }
} 
return count;
}
```

}